# How to test a MessageBox in wpf?

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, messagebox, fluent-assertions

I'm going to do some unit tests and I am struggling with a `MessageBox`. I have a `MessageBox` that is showing a text and an "Ok" button in my code. When I trying to unit test the method that contains the `MessageBox.Show("Text")`, it pops up in the unit test, too, and I have to click "Ok" before it can pass through, which is a bad.

Does anyone know how to go around it? I think I need some kind of code that fakes this `MessageBox` and clicking "Ok", but I dont know how to do this. I'm a junior programmer, so please explain it as easy as you can ;) and gladly with some code examples.

This is my code for the `MessageBox`:

```
public void GetPopUpWithErrorMessage()
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error Message", "text",
   MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
```

**Edit**
I just realised that Fluent Assertions is used in the project. Does anyone know how to implement that in the test code? is it the same way as @thatguy showed?

Comment: You need to create a service for showing messages. And in your tests, you should mock your service in order to prevent message box appearance.

Comment: Fluent assertions only provides extension methods to improve readability of tests outcomes, but that is independent of mocking. You still need a mocking framework. It works the same as shown in the answer. Your test code should be the same as before with the difference that you create a mock and pass it to your class, but that does not interfere with fluent assertions.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a service that implements an interface that you can mock in your tests.

```
public interface IMessageBoxService
{
   void ShowMessageBox(string title, string message);
}

public class MessageBoxService : IMessageBoxService
{
   public void ShowMessageBox(string title, string message)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OK);
   }
}
```

In the class where you use it, you would pass this service by its interface, e.g. in the constructor, so the class only knows its contract, but not its implementation.

```
public class MyClass
{
   private IMessageBoxService _messageBoxService;

   public MyClass(IMessageBoxService messageBoxService)
   {
      _messageBoxService = messageBoxService;
   }

   public void GetPopUpWithErrorMessage()
   {
      _messageBoxService.ShowMessageBox("text", "Error Message");
   }
}
```

In the test class, you need to use a mocking framework like [*Moq*](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) that creates a mock object from an interface, which is just a stub that you can use to inject the behavior for any method or property that you use in your test.

In this example using *NUnit* and *Moq*, `messageBoxService` is created as a mock object that implements the `IMessageBoxService` interface. All methods do nothing unless you specify what they should do or return via `Setup`, but that is another topic. The last line shows how you could check if a sepcific method on the mock was invoked during the test.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTest
{
   [Test]
   public void MyTest()
   {
      var messageBoxService = Mock.Of<IMessageBoxService>();
      var myClass = new MyClass(messageBoxService);

      // ...your test code.

      // Checks if the "ShowMessageBox" method in the service was called with any strings
      Mock.Get(messageBoxService).Verify(mock => mock.ShowMessageBox(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()));
   }
}
```

Creating a service and an interface is not just useful for mocking, but also for separating view and logic, as you can extract the calling of a message box to a service which has an implementation hidden behind an interface. Moreover you can easily implement dependency injection via constructors.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do something similar in my code and see if it works! :)